# Combine path, file strings and literals for path

Tags: powershell, filepath

Trying to combine a path, filename, and add some text along with a variable for `Out-File` log.

I've tried many alternatives unsuccessfully and need assistance;

```bsh
FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
$OldVersion = C:\Temp\TestFile.txt
$OldPath = (Get-Item $OldVersion).DirectoryName
$OldBaseName = (Get-Item $OldVersion).BaseName
ErrFile = Join-Path $OldPath OldBaseName

Out-File -FilePath "$ErrFile_$FormattedDate Error.txt"
Out-File -FilePath "$($OldPath)$($OldBaseName)_$($FormattedDate)_Error.txt"
```

...just two examples.

I've tried many other combinations and driving me crazy.

Basically I want it to be.

```
C:\Temp\TestFile_2017-08-24 16:51:36_Error.txt
```

---

**Update:**

I've tried both

```
$filename = '{0}_{1:s}_Error{2}' -f $basename, (Get-Date), $extension
```

I get `_2017-08-25T13:02:17_Error.txt` but no basename (`TestFile`).

```
$newpath = "${dirname}\${basename}_${date}_Error${extension}"
```

I get

> A drive with the name '_2017-08-25 13' does not exists.

Can you also explain or provide a resource of what `'{0}_{1:s}_Error{2}'` and/or `'{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}_Error{2}'` does?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) for constructing the filename and [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-3.0) for building the path.

```bsh
$oldpath   = 'C:\Temp\TestFile.txt'

$basename  = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($oldpath)
$extension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($oldpath)

$filename  = '{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}_Error{2}' -f $basename, (Get-Date), $extension

$newpath   = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($oldpath)) $filename
```

Unless you must have the space in the date format you could simplify the format string by using the [standard sortable format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable) (`s`) that will produce date strings like `2017-08-24T23:58:25` instead of `2017-08-24 23:58:25`.

```bsh
$filename  = '{0}_{1:s}_Error{2}' -f $basename, (Get-Date), $extension
```

---

If you want to construct the path as a string with inline variables you need to make sure that the underscores in your file name are kept separate from the variable name. Because underscores are valid name components for variable names `$var_` is the variable `var_`, not the variable `var` followed by a literal underscore. Use curly braces to ensure that variables and literal underscores don't get mixed up.

```bsh
$oldpath   = 'C:\Temp\TestFile.txt'

$date      = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
$dirname   = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($oldpath)
$basename  = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($oldpath)
$extension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($oldpath)

$newpath   = "${dirname}\${basename}_${date}_Error${extension}"
```

---

**Addendum:** Your file names should not contain colons. Colons in Windows paths either terminate a drive name or separate the file name from the name of an [alternate data stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/). Your date format string should rather be something like `yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss` or `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss` to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: I've tried both;
`$filename  = '{0}_{1:s}_Error{2}' -f $basename, (Get-Date), $extension`
I get "_2017-08-25T13:02:17_Error.txt" but no basename (TestFile)

'$newpath   = "${dirname}\${basename}_${date}_Error${extension}"'

I get "A drive with the name '\_2017-08-25 13' does not exists.

Can you also explain or provide a resource of what;
'{0}_{1:s}_Error{2}' and/or '{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}_Error{2}' does?

Comment: The first code snipped needed a correction (the first argument to `Join-Path` must be in parentheses). I tested the first and the last snippet with PowerShell v2 and v3, and they work correctly. Please provide evidence if they don't work for you. Show the full code you were using and the full output that code produced.

Comment: *Can you also explain or provide a resource of what; '{0}_{1:s}_Error{2}' and/or '{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}_Error{2}' does?* I already did that. Please read my answer.